# What is the proper way of testing simple CRUD operations with Pytest to ensure correct reads and writes? Function object instead of value is returned

Tags: pytest, python-3.7, assert

Using `Pytest`, I am trying to test a simple database `read` function and an `update` function.
The `update` function needs to be run first to ensure the test database has the values we will test for in our `read` function.

In `/src` there is my main script, here are the `read`, `update`, `delete` functions:

```
    async def read(self, collection, query=None, mods=None):

        Table = self._cache.classes[collection]

        async with self._session() as session:
            matches = set(Table.__mapper__.columns.keys()) & set(mods['fields'])

            for m in matches:
                q = select(getattr(Table, m))
                q = q.filter_by(**query)

                result = await session.execute(q)

            return [row for row in result]

    async def update(self, collection, query, data):

        Table = self._cache.classes[collection]

        async with self._session() as s:
            q = sa_update(Table).filter_by(**query)
            q = q.values(**data)

            await s.execute(q)
            await s.commit()

    async def delete_collection(self, table_name, syncro_engine=sync_engine):
        table = self.retrieve_table_obj(table_name)
        async with self._engine.begin() as conn:
            await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.drop_all(syncro_engine, [table], checkfirst=True))
```

When running `read` the output is `[('Wonderland',)]` so this is what I am testing in `assert` in `Pytest`.

In `/test` I have a `conftest.py` file that has these three functions:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_update():
    def get_update(collection, query, data):
        return asyncio.run(DB.update(collection, query, data))
    return get_update


@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def test_read():
    def get_read(collection, query, mods):
        return asyncio.run(DB.read(collection, query, mods))
    return get_read

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def drop_table():
    def get_delete_tables(table_name, sync_engine):
        return asyncio.run(DB.delete_collection(table_name, sync_engine))
    return get_delete_tables
```

Then the tests get run in `test_db.py`:

```
# Tests 'update' by updating user 'Alice' with 'org' 'Wonderland'
# Doesn't return anything, using it to ensure the correct values are in test_db to test the read function
@pytest.mark.parametrize('function_input, expected',
                         [("'user', {'name': 'Alice'}, {'org': 'Wonderland'})", "[('Wonderland',)]")])
def test_update(test_update, function_input, expected):
    test_update


# Tests  'read' by reading the just-updated values 
@pytest.mark.parametrize('function_input, expected',
                         [("'user', query={'name': 'Alice'}, mods={'fields': ['name', 'org']})", "[('Wonderland',)]")])
def test_read(test_read, function_input, expected):
    assert test_read == expected

# Tests that tables are dropped cleanly by dropping a given table then checking for that table name
@pytest.mark.parametrize('fn_input1, fn_input2, expected',
                         [('image', sync_engine, 'image')])
def test_drop_table(drop_table, collection_names, fn_input1, fn_input2, expected):
    # First drop the table
    drop_table(fn_input1, fn_input2)
    # Now check that it no longer exists
    with pytest.raises(KeyError) as error_info:
        assert fn_input1 in collection_names
        raise KeyError
    assert error_info.type is KeyError
```

Running `test_drop_table` does not drop anything from `test_db` even though it's being passed the correct database `test_db` and its counterpart in the main script in `/src` works properly.

When I run this `test_read` test it fails:

```
>       assert test_read == expected
E       assert <function test_read.<locals>.get_read at 0x7f1fa6beed08> == "[('Wonderland',)]"
```

How can I access the actual returned value to `assert` against, i.e. `[('Wonderland',)]`, rather than the `<function object>`?

Comment: As you return a function object in your fixture, you have to call that function in your test. As an aside - it is probably not a good idea to name your fixtures `test_xxx`, especially as they have the same name as the actual tests.

Comment: Thanks! Can you clarify what you mean by calling that function in my test? For ex, in `conftest.py` there is a fixture `drop_table` which calls `get_delete_tables`. It is set up this way so that I can pass in parameters from `test_db.py` to the function that the fixture is calling. I don't actually need a return statement from `get_delete_tables`. I just need to access the main script function (`asyncio.run(DB.delete_collection(table_name, sync_engine))`) `get_delete_tables` calls. So to call this fixture in the test I call `drop_tables`, and pass in the params to 'get_delete_tables'.

Comment: All your fixtures don't do anything, they just return a function pointer. In `test_drop_table` you actually call the function, but in the other tests you don't. I actually don't understand what the tests shall do - the description for `test_update` sounds as if this thought as a setup, though in that case it should be a fixture, and should actually do something (currently it does nothing). The second test also does not call anything, it just compares the function pointer against the srguments - I would expect that you want to call the function instead.

Comment: Ahh okay! So here is the functionality I want to achieve: In the fixture I simply want that function to be called. I don't always necessarily need a return value from that function. So it seems like I should be only using the fixtures if I want to use a returned value from it in `test_db.py`? If I simply want to test a function like `drop_table` I should call it directly in `test_db.py` without involving any fixtures?

Comment: Yes, looks like you don't need a fixture here. You can use fixtures without a return value, especially for setup/teardown -like functionality (where you do the setup before the `yield` and the teardown after the `yield`), but in this case you have to know the arguments for the call in the fixture, which you probably don't have in your case.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying :) And just to check that this is correct: any given fixture will be called in one of three instances: it's part of the reserved namespaces that pytest runs automatically at the start of tests OR the fixture has the `autouse` flag above it OR the main `test.py` file explicitly calls that fixture

Comment: Yes, if by "calls that fixture" you mean "put its name into the test arguments". There is also  @pytest.mark.usefixtures that can be used in a module or class.

Comment: Thanks for the help